# ResourceExhaustedError while using EfficientNet in keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I am using google colab. While using `EfficientNetB3` i am getting the following error
`Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[15,95,95,192] and type float`

I understand this because my data does not fit in GPU. But when I try `InceptionResNetV2` i did not get any error.

Number of trainable parameters in `EfficientNetB3` is `22,220,824`
Number of trainable parameters in `InceptionResNetV2` is `109,380,744`

Number of trainable parameters  in `InceptionResNetV2` are `5` time more than `EfficientNetB3`. So I am expecting `InceptionResNetV2`to throw error not `EfficientNetB3`.

Any idea why I am getting resource error in `EfficientNetB3`?

Note: I am using two parallel networks and these parameters are the sum of both network's parameters.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing using tf.keras.applications, where EfficientNetB3 (48MB with 12M parameters) uses almost exactly the same memory as Xception (88MB with 23M parameters). EfficientNetB4 is giving me OOM errors, even though that should also be a smaller model with fewer parameters than Xception

Answer (score 0):

All the papers seem be using TPUs to run the efficientNets. I have a feeling there is something else that is making it use far more memory. I agree it isn't intuitive since there is less training params in efficientNets. However, it does seem you need to actually be using TPUs to do it. So basically this would require using some cloud service that gives you access to TPUs ect...